# Get CButton control name from resource id?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, mfc, cbutton

I am using C++ MFC, and have created a simple dialog with CButtons, each of them mapped with its .bitmap files and resource ids (ID_BUTTON*) in a .rc script file.

Similar lines are present in my .rc file, in `DIALOG` description:

```
CONTROL         "TEST|Button7",ID_BUTTON2,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,234,29,30,71
```

In my project I am trying to get the resource id of each `CButton` object. I did it with this:

```
int getID = this->GetDlgCtrlID();
```

But how can I use my resource ID further to get the `CButton` control text value? Meaning this:

```
"TEST|Button7"
```

If not, is there a specific way to get it?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you refer to "resource name" which would surely be `ID_BUTTON2`. Perhaps you should re-word it because the answer you accepted shows you how to get the text value associated with the control which is not the same as the resource name.

Comment: Control name instead then. Sorry about that ! Still new to MFC and I am prone to typo errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually very simple. Where you use `int getID = this->GetDlgCtrlID();` to get the resource ID, you can use this code to get the control's name:

```
CString buttonName;
this->GetWindowText(buttonName);
```

PS: Assuming the calls are made inside a class member function, then you don't actually *need* the `this->` pointer; just call the `GetWindowText()` or `GetDlgCtrlID()` functions. (But using `this->` does no harm, and can make code a bit clearer to read.)

If you want to get the text for a button from *outside* the button's own class functions - say, from the parent dialog box handler, you can use this:

```
CString buttonName;
GetDlgItem(idValue)->GetWindowText(buttonName);
```

Where `idValue` is the resource ID of the button (or any other control) concerned.